# what would be the encoding of a bnez MIPS instruction?

Tags: mips

What would be the encoding of this last instruction if the address of the Loop is 0x00012344?

```
Loop:
    addu $a0, $0, $t0
    ori $v0, $0, 4
    syscall
    addi $t0, $t0, -1
    bnez $t0, Loop
```

this last instruction is equivalent to:

```
bne $t0, $0, Loop
```

however, How would I write this in machine code?

this is how for I got:

```
000101 01000 00000 iiiii iiiii iiiiii
```

I dont know what to but for the i's here. The address of Loop is 0x00012344 however that is a 17 bit binary number. I only have 16 bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branch in MIPS works with offsets (shifted left 2 positions), not absolute addresses.

> BNE -- Branch on not equal
>
> Description:
>
> Branches if the two registers are not equal
>
> Operation:
>
> if $s != $t **advance_pc (offset << 2)**); else advance_pc (4);
>
> Syntax:
>
> bne $s, $t, offset
>
> Encoding:
>
> 0001 01ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii

[Source](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)

So it's `Loop` offset from the `BNE` instruction that should go on the `i` part, not its absolute address.

---

**EDIT**: with edited question code:

```
Loop:
    addu $a0, $0, $t0
    ori $v0, $0, 4
    syscall
    addi $t0, $t0, -1
    bnez $t0, Loop
```

Since all MIPS instructions are 32-bit wide (4 bytes), we can calculate offset easily:

- `Loop` address is -4 instructions from BNEZ instruction, so it's -4 x 4 = -16 bytes away.
- But we need to add one more word because in MIPS PC was already incremented by 4 and when BNEZ is executing, PC is already pointing to next instruction (see [delay slot in MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot)). So final offset is -20 = -(0x14) = 0xFFFEC.
- We shift right 2 positions (divide by 4) to get this offset in *words* (instead of bytes): 0xFFFEC >> 2 = 0xFFFB

You can also do it by counting by words directly:

- `Loop` address is -4 instructions from BNEZ instruction
- Additional -1 because PC already incremented: -5
- -5 = -(0x5) = 0xFFFB

So we got 0xFFFB for `i` part; so whole instruction is `0x1500FFFB`.

By the way you can check this with any MIPS assembler or [simulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/).

*(Screenshot from MARS simulator)*

[image: MARS simulator, Text segment view]

Comment: can you show me what the loop offset would be? can you show the complete encoding so I can follow/confirm what you are telling me?

Comment: would this be the machine code then? 000101 01000 00000 0100100011010001

Comment: I don't know the exact encoding because I don't know Loop and BNE addresses.

Comment: i have the loop address in my post

Comment: From my previous comment: *"Loop and BNE addresses"*.

Comment: hey I added the previous instructions. for the Imm value, I don't know what PC starts at. I think after each instruction, PC increases by 4 but I don't know what PC starts at and I don't know what to do with the Loop address

Comment: I edited the answer. PC absolute value is irrelevant, as I said it's the **offset** (the difference) that matters for a branch instruction.